# What is the EOBT validity period, if any, for non-CDM airports?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airline-operations, ground-operations, airport-operations

The validity period for the EOBT in CDM compliant airports is +/- 15 minutes from the TOBT. My understanding is that EOBT does not exist in non-CDM airports, so is there any validity period? I assume the SOBT is used as the target?